# Why was the Falcon 9 wash/paint question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Link to Q: [Do Falcon 9s get a thorough wash or a fresh coat of paint (they look clean pre-reflight)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52141/32596)

It was [voted leave open the first time](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/close/26334), but it was closed, and the reopen review [was also 3x leave closed](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/26382).

I made a **clear edit** once someone found the possible dupe explaining why it is not. The linked photo that prompted the question does show a clean Falcon 9, and a perfect explanation was given. Further, the duplicate does **not** ask about washing, only painting.

I'd also argue the newer question presents the problem better, and the answers are more thorough. *Given that,* I'd recommend **reopening, and then closing the older question as dupe of the newer** per the consensus on the main Meta:

> If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.
> [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643)

Regardless of a second closure/merging, the newer one is not a duplicate of the older one IMO, which I explained in an edit to the question, and is apparent from the answers.

Comment: There is some "inertial thinking" that newer must be closed as dupe of older and when it results in a bad outcome resorting to meta is necessary. That said, I never make much headway with "my question is better" :-) Can you demonstrate that the *answers* on the newer question better answer both questions than those on the old one for example? Since Stack Exchange is all about answers, I think that that argument is going to be helpful if not necessary to flip the polarity of a community induced duplicate close.

Comment: Different but somewhat similar situation [Are these two similar questions ripe for merging?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741) I may have had others in the past as well.